# How to solve error in TukeyHSD (R language)

Tags: r, math, statistics

I always get this error when I want to run the `TukeyHSD()` for my 2x2 ANOVA.
Here`s the ANOVA I did:

```
anova_result <- aov(mean_rt ~ congruency * coloring + Error(participant / congruency), data = agg_dat)

And the results:
summary(anova_result)

Error: participant
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
coloring    1   0.00 0.00020   0.003  0.955
Residuals 351  22.61 0.06442               

Error: participant:congruency
                     Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
congruency            1  0.231 0.23053  25.218 8.16e-07 ***
congruency:coloring   1  0.035 0.03459   3.784   0.0525 .  
Residuals           351  3.209 0.00914                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1



TukeyHSD(anova_result)
```

> Error in UseMethod("TukeyHSD") :
> no applicable method for 'TukeyHSD' applied to an object of class "c('aovlist', 'listof')".

Obviously I used function `aov`:

```
class(anova_result)
[1] "aovlist" "listof"
```

How can I solve this problem?
I don`t know what to try anymore.

Comment: This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534883/error-in-tukeyhsd-in-r).